# Convert IQueryable to IOrderedQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 2 tables : Items and ItemMetrics. Items contains my items and ItemMetrics contains statistics about those items.

I'm trying to sort a list of Items by the corresponding statistic Weight.
I got it to work using a subquery, but I thought it was a little inefficent and could be optimized...

```
items.OrderBy(item => (from metric in Context.ItemMetrics where item.ItemId == metric.ItemId select metric.Weight).FirstOrDefault());
```

...So I am trying to accomplish the same thing using a join...

```
from item in items join metric in ItemMetrics on item.ItemId equals metric.ItemId orderby metric.Weight select item;
```

This is working fine in LINQPad. I need to return an IOrderedQueryable for a supplmentary method to do some paging using Skip and Take, but the compiler is telling me the result of this query is an IQueryable.

The only way I can think of explictly implying IOrderedQueryable is wrapping the query in

```
OrderBy(x => 0)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that an `IOrderedQueryable` needs to be able to apply a secondary ordering - and by the time you've projected the item/metric pair to just an item, you've lost the primary ordering.

One approach would be to defer the projection until later:

```
var ordered = items.Join(ItemMetrics,
                         item => item.ItemId,
                         metric => metric.ItemId,
                         (item, metric) => new { item, metric })
                   .OrderBy(pair => pair.Metric.Weight);
var paged = ApplyPaging(ordered, pageConfiguration); // Whatever
var query = paged.Select(pair => pair.Item);
```

That's assuming `ApplyPaging` (or whatever you're using) returns an `IQueryable` or an `IOrderedQueryable`.

Comment: Thanks for that. One question: Is it safe to just cast the result to IOrderedQueryable<Item>? I didn't do it before because I've had Skip and Take complain before but after posting I just added it as a guess and it works.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall: Cast which result? The one from your original query? I'm surprised that works, to be honest... I wouldn't personally rely on it, as it sounds like it's a convenient implementation detail at the moment. If my approach works, I'd go with that instead.